# facing issue with Sonarqube Upgradation

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.6

We are facing issue in SonarQube upgradation, Current Version of SonarQube running in production is : 5.6.5 (OSS- Community Edition) and expected version is 7.2.

Migration Path tried: (As suggested in Sonarqube upgrade guide)

```
         Current Version | Higher Version
Trial1 : 5.6.5           => 6.7 => 7.2
Trial2 : 5.6.5           => 6.2 => 6.7
Trial3 : 5.6.5           => 6.0 => 6.2
Trial4 : 5.6.5           => 5.6.7 
Trail5 : 5.6.5           => 5.6.6
```

Database in use: Postgres SQL 
Server OS where Sonarqube hosted is RHEL 7 (For upgradation we tried with both windows and RHEL)

Highlights :

- In all above mentioned paths we are facing issue that after upgradation its only showing 5 projects out of 107 projects available in the database whereas in the current production instance which is Sonarqube 5.6.5 its shows all 107 projects.
- Database dump and restore from production instance to test server has no error reported in logs.
- Plugins are upgraded as per compatibility matrix shared by SonarSource
- Projects Analyzed language : Java, C#, JavaScript and XML.
- No errors reported in Sonarqube Logs
- After migration new analysis is also working fine issue that it’s not showing all previous analyzed projects
- And for 5 projects which are visible after migration its showing history as well

We have tried restarting Sonarqube after deleting es directory after upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

First, there's no need to upgrade to intermediate, non-LTS versions.

Now regarding your missing projects post-upgrade, it's likely that you have corrupt Elasticsearch indices. Try:

- stop server
- delete `$SONARQUBE_HOME/data/es` (or `/es5` depending on the version)
- restart the server

It will take a little while for your indices to rebuild, but then you should be good.